# How to snap bottom face of cone to top face of cylinder

Tags: snapping

I want to make something similar to an arrow. How can I snap center of base of cone to center of top face of a cylinder? I tried every option near the famous magnet icon and also the combinations with G and B, without luck. Snapping things with blender is one of the hardest things in the world.

Comment: Blender snapping does take a bit of getting used to.. and IMO could still do wirh improvement.. not an answer, but from a modelling point of view, don't forget [this option](https://imgur.com/a/RB4ZpMw)

Comment: Nice alternative thanks

Comment: @RobinBetts _Extrude Faces Along Normals_? It is a planar n-gon, why not simply extrude with `E`? A single face is by default extruded along its normal...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  .. Oops, muscle-memory :D I think I've got into the habit of Alt-E. all the time. ...  If you're there, upstream, .. Gordon's onto it.  :)

Comment: Yes I was able to just extrude with E thanks. BTW what is that big yellow circle appearing when I try to extrude? Or when I did inset faces, the big white circle... (and somewhere else there was a big black circle)... I can do nothing to them or get rid of them. ))

Answer (score 3):

1. select this face on the cone
2. shift-s -> cursor to selected
3. tab -> object mode
4. object -> set origin to 3d cursor
5. snapping settings:

[image]

6. [image]
7. unfortunately you still don't have it in the middle of the face (or you just eyeball it. Or you can create now a vertex in the middle of the cylinder face and snap to vertex...but honestly, i would use align tools (free add-on, comes with Blender)

A) select both objects -> click -> select the cone then G Z Z done

[image]

Comment: I activated align tools and aligned them. then I selected cone, did GZZ but the bottom of cone still does not snap to top of cylinder.

Comment: that's right - the g z z i did eyeball it. I honestly think, that you should do it like Robin wrote in the comments, because that's quicker and more accurate

Comment: Ok. At least now I feel better that even experienced people cannot do it. They should definitely improve snap feature then. Thanks a lot for the answer.